# Why is flask app throwing an error in cpanel

Tags: flask, cpanel

Can anyone let me know how to deploy a flask app on a personal website using CPanel

I have tried running it through the virtualenv but did not work

Answer (score 0):

Flask is a micro framework that runs in a Python instance, and not as a set of files that are served from a web server, like HTML or PHP. Most likely you will need another hosting provider that hosts web applications like [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) or use a VPS instead.

On the other hand, most shared hosting providers do not allow you to install custom libraries that need to be compiled.